# What is wrong with this Fortran write-statement?

Tags: fortran

The only thing I need, having no experience with Fortran at all, is to add some debugging statements. Here's what drives me nuts: I originally wanted to print out some statements I can transfer directly to C++:

```
write(*,*) 'facets_refined_mesh[', Ray( 1, i ) - 1, '].set_plot_color(0,0,1);'
```

The compiler (under MinGW) complains about an *Unterminated character constant* at the closing bracket ']'. Thinking it might have something to do with 'special characters' I tried to narrow the error down:

```
write(*,*) 'facetsrefinedmesh', Ray( 1, i ) - 1, 'setplotcolor'
```

which still gives the same error, but shortening the text to:

```
write(*,*) 'blah', Ray( 1, i ) - 1, 'blah'
```

is perfectly OK for the compiler. I expect at least a  bit of logic in a programming language or its compiler, but this doesn't make sense at all. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**, complete error:

```
C:\Users\boschmajj\Documents\RAPPORT_F>gfortran.exe -c *.f
main.f:213:64:

        write(*,*) 'facets_refined_mesh[', Ray( 1, i ) - 1, '].set_plot_color(0,0,1);'
                                                            1
Error: Unterminated character constant beginning at (1)
```

I tried to break things into pieces, but then an error occurs here:

```
C:\Users\boschmajj\Documents\RAPPORT_F>gfortran.exe -c *.f
main.f:223:41:

        write(*,'(A)', advance='no') 'viewer::add_ray(facets_refined_mesh['
                                     1
Error: Unterminated character constant beginning at (1)
```

Comment: Please show the exact and complete output from the compiler, and say how long your line is

Comment: @francescalus: see edit

Comment: As @francescalus expected, looks like fixed formatted code, and the mentioned line is longer than 72 characters. So distribute line over multiple lines or rewrite code to free formatted code (advised)

Comment: Like @albert said in his comment, there's apparently a 72 character limit for the code I have. Splitting things up further did the job, so thanks for pointing that out. But it still feels like 'really????'...

Comment: Well, what compiler are you using, what Fortran version/mode are you telling it to compile, and does it provide ways to opt-in to newer modes that don't have that old limitation?

Comment: Note the 72 character limit only applies to the old source format which was superceded 30 years ago

Comment: As @IanBush said, the 72 character limit (with also the first 6 positions reserved for label and continuation character) is for, the "old", fixed formatted code and the 132 character limit is for the free formatted code.

Comment: @underscore_d: now I know what the problem was, it does answer my question. For me the only required thing was: get it compiled, add some debug-statements where required and don't bother about the rest. So now I find out about the different standards, but given the fact that the whole (old!) Fortran project will literally be ditched there is no use to investigate that further.